# Echoing result of using $_GET to query MySQL w/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, get

How do I echo the result of this code?

Edit: Here's the new code. Based off the example from the official PHP site.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$getid = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pasteinfo WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $getid);


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($paste)
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf ("%s \n", $paste);
        }

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: You fetch it: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @MarcB so my new code has while ($stmt->fetch()) { printf(%s); } right under $stmt->execute(); but it makes the page straight up unavailable?

Comment: or you could actually read the examples in the linked documentation, so you actually USE IT CORRECTLY. plus, `printf(%s)` is a flat-out syntax error.

Comment: @MarcB pastebin.com/C7ydHJuG my bad! New code is there, having the same problem.

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a remote link.

Comment: You reassigned `$stmt`, and didn't call `bind_param` on the new statement.

Answer (score 0):

After you called `bind_param()`, you prepared the statement again, so the new statement doesn't have the parameter bound. You're also missing a `;` after the call to `bind_result()`.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$getid = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pasteinfo WHERE id = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $getid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($paste);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s \n", $paste);
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

You also should have the same number of variables in `bind_result` as the number of columns you're selecting. It might be OK to have fewer, and it will just ignore the remaining columns, I'm not sure. It's best to select specific columns rather than `select *`, because depending on the order of columns in the table definition is dangerous.